# The sum of three consecutive terms of an Arithmetic progression is $18$ and their product is $120$. Find the terms.

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm currently going through some questions on series and stumbled on this.

The sum of three consecutive terms of an Arithmetic progression is $18$ and their product is $120$. Find the terms.

I attempted it like this but I think I'm wrong cause the products is giving me $210$.

$x + (x+1) +(x+2) = 18$;

$3x +3 = 18;$

$3x = 15;$

$x=5,$ The three consecutive numbers are

$5, 6, 7$;

Appreciate the assistance.

Comment: the difference isnt necessarily 1 !!

Comment: You took a particular case. Or it seems that you just focus on consecutive terms and ignore that they are consecutive terms in Arithmetic Progression.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, the consecutive terms can differ by any number, say $d$, instead of just $1$. So, the three numbers are better represented as $x-d,x,$ and $x+d$.

Then,
$$3x=18 \Rightarrow x=6$$
and
$$x(x^2-d^2)=120$$
$$6(36-d^2)=120$$
$$36-d^2=20$$
$$d^2=16$$
$$d=\pm4$$

The numbers thus are $\{2,6,10\}$ or $\{10,6,2\}$.

Comment: nice shortcut +1

Comment: I understand now. Thank you sir.

Answer (score 0):

Three terms in an arkthmetic progression ... one of them is the average which is of course one-third the sum, then you can infer the sum and product of the other two ... .

Answer (score -1):

Let the thee consecutive numbers in arithmetic progression be:

$$(n-d), n , (n+d)$$

where $d$ is the common diffrence.

Since the sum of the three consecutive numbers is $18$,
$$(n-d)+n+(n+d)=18$$
$$3n=18$$
$$n=6$$

The product is $120$;
$$(n-d)*n*(n+d)=120$$
$$(n^2-d^2)n=120$$

But $n=6$. Therefore
$$(6^2 - d^2)6=120$$
$$(36-d^2)=20$$
$$-d^2=20-36$$
$$d^2=16$$
$$d=4\text{ or }d= -4$$

The possible arithmetic progressions are:
$$2,6,10,\text{ or }10,6,2.$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your answer adds nothing new to the already existing answers.

Answer (score -2):

Let $a_0=0$ and $a_1=1$. Then let the arithmetic progression for your sequence be

$a_n = a_(n-1) + a_(n-2)$

You will get a sequence {3,5,8} which 3*5*8=120

This is the Fibonacci sequence.

Comment: $3,5,8$ are not an arithmetic progression. **By definition** an arithmetic progression is a sequence where the differencew between successive terms is a constant, and $5-3\ne 8-5$.

Comment: Oof. So it seems. Whoops. I just made a major assumption about the definition heh. The accepted answer is pretty direct.